# Debug HTTP status code of a big urls list

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, python

I have a list of urls and I need to debug it, eliminating those that are invalid or dead. For this I use the following script in bash ([based on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136022/script-to-get-the-http-status-code-of-a-list-of-urls)):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read LINE; do
    curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}' "$LINE"
    echo " $LINE"
done < url-list.txt
```

the problem is that it can take days/months depending on the size of the list (in my case millions of lines).

**Is there any way to do this faster?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to know if the website is still there, you could use the
[fping command](https://linux.die.net/man/8/fping),
which does a quick test and can accept a file containing a list of websites:

> Description
>
> fping is a like program which uses the Internet Control Message
>   Protocol (ICMP) echo request to determine if a target host is
>   responding. fping differs from ping in that you can specify any number
>   of targets on the command line, or specify a file containing the lists
>   of targets to ping. Instead of sending to one target until it times
>   out or replies, fping will send out a ping packet and move on to the
>   next target in a round-robin fashion.

Example :

```
fping < fping.txt
```

For more examples see
[Fping – A High Performance Ping Tool for Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/ping-multiple-linux-hosts-using-fping/).

Comment: for example....

Comment: Lots of. Some added above.

Comment: An idea for gaining speed that will work with any product is to use IP addresses and so avoid DNS. Fping will also simplify your bash script, doing the whole work by itself. And I believe that it must be faster than curl, in that it's only doing an ICMP request.

Comment: That's not what the man page says. See the example at the end.

Comment: fping writes the output to the screen (RAM) and then to the output file (instead of directly to the output file). And because the list is very large, the system collapses. And if there is a power cut, work is lost. I do not see any parameters to force fping to write directly to the output file

Comment: Yes, not very efficiently programmed. You could perhaps on the one hand reduce the output options as much as possible and on the other hand divide the list into manageable-sized files.

Comment: definitely fping is bad for this. It is not fast enough and it makes the system collapse by writing the output in RAM

Comment: It sounds like the best tool for the job - the problem is using it correctly, Doing so in batches is better than going back to a script that does it one at a time. Staring a process is also a slow operation.

Comment: Im confused as to  how this was.the correct answer - From reading the provided.information this uses.ICMP to test host reachabilty, but I cant see how it tests URLs and provides back a status code?

Comment: @davidgo: This apparently was the requirement.

Comment: @harrymc I contacted the creator of fping and he replied: "I think that doing that with a redirect as you did works just fine. It does not mean that everything is stored in RAM first". I have verified this, and the functioning of fping is quite strange. After executing the command and after a while of running (in my case 48 hours), start writing to the output file. Then, without having another better proposal, yours is the correct one. PD: as additional data, fping only processed 297685 urls from my list and stopped

Answer (score 1):

The bottleneck is likely the latency of response time of the server, so changing the language is not likely to make a massive difference.

If the server is robust you could look at launching requests in parellel, either by breaking the list into chunks and running multiple invocations simultaneoysly, or by rewriting the script to background processes (but dont try open everything simultaneously, you need to limit yourself(

Another possibility might be more reactive but lower overhead and able to reveal other uses if you control the sites - change the logging of thevserver and look at error codes people have seen. You might want to use something like nagios to additionally monitor latency and remote sight reachability.